# Changing ordering of model in the admin views

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a User model in Django, in which I defined `class Meta` with ordering. It's defined like this:

```py
class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('user')
    verbose_name_plural = _('users')
    ordering = ('-speedy_net_site_profile__last_visit',)
    swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
```

But, I have two apps - Speedy Net and Speedy Match, and in Speedy Match I want a different order (

```py
    ordering = ('-speedy_match_site_profile__last_visit',)
```

). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ordering to `admin.py` in your apps. Like:

```
class SpeedyNetAdmin(models.admin):
    .....
    ordering = ('-speedy_net_site_profile__last_visit',)
```

[Refs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields)

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I was not aware of this feature.